# Is it possible to apply a template to SharePoint online services "home" tab?

Tags: sharepoint

I can apply a template to a subsite when creating it, however, on the home/parent site, there does not seem to be an option to apply a template. You can only list the templates.

> Note: This is for: Microsoft
>   SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MetaVis Architect to create a SharePoint Site Template and then use MetaVis Site Creator to deploy that MetaVis SharePoint Template to BPOS Microsoft online.  You can get a free trial at [www.metavistech.com](http://www.metavistech.com).  You can also use MetaVis Architect Suite to move your site structure and content to BPOS Microsoft online.

Comment: Hi Peter,

is this not possible with SharePoint Designer?

Thanks,
Tony.